# Is there a word or phrase to describe a job that requires a college degree?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to think of a way to say a person has a job that is (more than likely) only available to the college educated. The idea is to convey a level of success.

The terms I've thought of are:

- White-collar job - Conveys office work, but seems too broad. This could apply to basic clerical work. Plus, there are some educated positions that might not be "white-collar."
- Professional position - What I'm leaning towards most. It gives the idea they're working in their field as a "professional."

An example of where it might be used is:

> "My son is doing quite well for himself, he has a _________ and is living on his own already."

Comment: I’d likeky say, “He has a job using his degree...”

Comment: "White-collar job" is the correct term.  Clerical work is "pink-collar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the sentence, I think "graduate job" would work.  Admittedly, it's not a common construction, but it would be clearly understood by everyone and convey precisely what you intend.  Beyond that, I think your 'professional position' is good, if a bit more vague and not propping the degree up as much.

Comment: "Graduate job" strongly implies work involving a post-Bachelor degree.  Likewise, "professional position", implies a job requiring professional certification (doctor, lawyer, CPA, Professional engineer).